# How do I convert a custom field to a php date format?

Tags: php, date-time

I have a custom field with an example value of `2018/02/28 16:21`.

How do I convert that to `28th February 2018 at 16:21`

Comment: there is nothing wordpress-y about this

Comment: Yes there is, it pertains directly to custom fields. I win :)

Comment: it pertains to any value formatted as a date. nothing specific to custom values.

Comment: In my situation it pertains to a WP custom field. Having fun?

Comment: as long as you enjoy asking questions and answering them only for them to be virtually removed from the site, there is no problem at all.

Comment: I asked a question, I found the answer, I answered it (there's provision that). run away now.

Comment: while you're giving it to those who take the time to answer their own questions to help others who may be watching the thread... you could go after this poor sod... https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35317/how-to-alter-query-order-direction-using-query-setorder-asc-inside-a-p?rq=1

Comment: low quality questions that swamp the site reduce its quality and usefulness.

Answer (score 0):

Found it...

```
$date = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'CUSTOM-FIELD-HERE', true );

if( $date != '' ) {
    echo date( "l jS F Y", strtotime( $date ) );
}
```